# Sql server 2005 sp3 problem with Ghost Cleanup

Tags: sql-server-2005

The Ghost Cleanup process is killing my server. I have tried everything and nothing seems to work:

- Tried to run dbcc checkdb (didn't get any errors)
- Tried rebuild indexes
- tried to restart services and even the server

Please any help to show me how can I get rid of this mess... thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

paul randal has written a few posts regarding the ghost process http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/search.aspx?q=ghost

he also talks about turning it off http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Turning-off-the-ghost-cleanup-task-for-a-performance-gain.aspx

Comment: I have tried the rebuild index option, didn't work,  I don't want to try option 611 because it's a production server